# Why does Monitor.Pulse need locked mutex? (.Net)

Tags: .net, mutex, monitor, pulse

[Monitor.Pulse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse.aspx) and PulseAll requires that the lock it operates on is locked at the time of call. This requirement seems unnecessary and detrimental for performance. My first idea was that this results in 2 wasted context switches, but this was corrected by nobugz below (thanks). I am still unsure whether it involves a *potential* for wasted context switches, as the other thread(s) which were waiting on the monitor are already available for the sheduler, but if they are scheduled, they will only be able to run a few instructions before hitting the mutex, and having to context-switch again. This would look much simpler and faster if the lock was unlocked *before* invoking the Monitor.Pulse.

[Pthread condition variables](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html) implement the same concept, but it does not have the above described limitation: you can call pthread_cond_broadcast even if you do not own the mutex. I see this as a proof that the requirement is not justified.

**Edit**:
I realize that a lock is required to protect the shared resource that is usually changed before the Monitor.Pulse. I was trying to say that that lock could have been unlocked after access to the resource but before the Pulse, given that Monitor would support this. This would help in limiting the lock to the shortest time during which the shared resource is accessed. As such:

```
void f(Item i)
{
  lock(somequeue) {
    somequeue.add(i);
  }
  Monitor.Pulse(somequeue);  // error
}
```

Comment: I had the exact same thinking than you when confronted to this. The Linked question on the list is mine and speaks the same concern. But in the end `pulse` is different than the low level `cond_var.signal` primitive, that's why it is not comparable. (c.f. my answer)

Answer (score 2):

The reason has to do with memory barriers and guaranteeing thread safety.

Shared variables (conditionals) that are used to determine whether a Pulse() is needed will be checked by all threads involved.  Without a memory barrier, the changes might be kept in a register and be invisible from one thread to another. Reads and writes can also be re-ordered when viewed across threads.

However, variables that are accessed from within a lock use a memory barrier, so they are accessible to all related threads. All operations within the lock appear to execute atomically from the perspective of other threads holding the same lock.

Also, multiple context switches aren't required, as you postulated.  Waiting threads are put in a (nominally FIFO) queue, and while they're triggered with Pulse(), they aren't fully runnable until the lock is relinquished (again, in part due to memory barriers).

For a good discussion of the issues, see: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Wait_and_Pulse

Comment: Putting a memory barrier in Pulse() wouldn't address the variables that are checked to see if Pulse() should be called. You know: `lock (someLock) { if (someVariable) Monitor.Pulse(); someVariable = false; }` It is actually possible to build a lightweight signaling mechanism with memory barriers alone... A memory barrier alone also wouldn't assure the (effective) atomicity of multiple operations inside the lock.

Comment: This link doesn't smell very good, for example: ` X86 and X64 processors always apply acquire-fences to reads and release-fences to writes` is wrong. he is confusing the MESI protocol and the flush of read writes operation from the instruction pipeline. c.f. intel documentation of XADD and other Locked prefix instructions. http://www.codemaestro.com/reviews/8

Comment: @RickNZ: If the code that does a pulse sets a flag which could be cleared by code in the wait loop, the code that calls pulse needs to acquire the lock before setting those flags.  It would seem semantically useful, however, to have a version of pulse which did not need to be within the lock, but which--if the lock is busy--would set a flag so that if the current holder of the lock calls wait *before exiting the lock* it would act as though it was pulsed immediately.  For example, suppose a wrapper object is supposed to encapsulate a thread.  If the wrapper is abandoned, the thread...

Comment: ...should die off at its earliest convenience.  If the thread sometimes will `Wait` until it's given data, but may sometimes hold a lock for awhile, it would be helpful if the finalize method could set a "shutdown" flag and then give a pulse, without having to acquire the lock first.  As it is, I know of no clean way to have the finalizer thread wake up the thread that's in the `Wait` without running the risk of its having to wait arbitrarily long to acquire the lock.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption that the Pulse() call invokes a thread switch is not correct.  It merely moves a thread from the wait queue to the ready queue.  The Exit() call makes the switch, to the thread that's first in the ready queue.

Comment: Thanks, but the scheduler can switch to a thread on the ready queue at any time, right? It doesn't need to wait for Exit(). So it can potentially switch to the other ready thread which will immediately hit the mutex, resulting in an other switch.

Comment: No, a thread in the ready queue is blocked on a native OS wait handle.  It isn't eligible for scheduling until you release the lock.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer in this paper:

http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64242/implementingcvs.pdf

it states:

> Since we’re considering this level of the threads implementation, I
>   should point out  one last performance problem, and what to do about
>   it. If Signal is called with the lock  m held, and if you’re running
>   on a multi-processor, the newly awoken thread is quite  likely to
>   start running immediately. This will cause it to block again a few
>   instructions  later at (2) when it wants to lock m. If you want to
>   avoid these extra reschedules, you  need to arrange to transfer the
>   thread directly from the condition variable queue to the  queue of
>   threads waiting for m. This is especially important in Java or C#,
>   which both  require that m is held when calling Signal or Broadcast.

The paper in its entirety is a bit vague and does not mention many implementation details, it is rather at pseudo/academical level. But apparently the guys who wrote it had responsibility in the actual .net implementation.

But roughly put: the signal is just a logical/user level operation and does not fire a primitive like condition variable signaling right away. It only does so on the lock scope exit. So there are no performance issues. It is truely disturbing when one is used to manipulate condition variables directly indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Wait is designed to be used with a conditional check.  If the conditional check were not done within a lock, it would be possible for the following sequence of events to occur:

1. The conditional check indicates a wait is necessary.

   Another thread changes the condition so a wait isn't necessary, and then does a Pulse or PulseAll.

   The first thread, having observed that a wait was necessary, performs a Wait.

Once that sequence of events occurs, it's entirely possible that nothing will ever Pulse the lock again (unless a situation arises where a wait would again be necessary, and again no longer be necessary).  Thread #1 could thus wait forever for an event that never arrives.

Putting the conditional check and Wait within a lock avoids this danger, since there will be no way for another thread to change the condition between the time the condition is checked and the time the Wait begins.  Consequently another thread that changes the Condition and does a Pulse can be assured that the first thread either checked the condition after it was changed (and thus avoided the wait) or else was executing the Wait when the Pulse executed (and was thus able to resume).