# Monitor.Pulse in C# appears suboptimal : must be in lock scope

Tags: c#, performance, locking, monitor, condition-variable

spoiler note: the question is the last phrase.

In C#, the classical pattern to use a condition variable is like this:

```
lock (answersQueue)
{
    answersQueue.Enqueue(c);
    Monitor.Pulse(answersQueue); // condition variable "notify one".
}
```

and some other thread:

```
lock (answersQueue)
{
    while (answersQueue.Count == 0)
    {
        // unlock answer queue and sleeps here until notified.
        Monitor.Wait(answersQueue);
    }
    ...
}
```

that's an example taken from my code.
if I place the Pulse outside of the lock scope, it doesn't compile.
however, it is the correct way:
c.f:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686903(v=vs.85).aspx
and:
http://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/threadprocesssynchronizationapis11_7.html
(search for "inside")

And indeed it is idiotic to signal the sleeping thread when you still are in your critical section. Because the sleeping thread CAN'T wake up (not immediately), BECAUSE it is INSIDE a criticial section as well !

Therefore, I hope that .NET or C# Pulse call is actually just flagging the lock object, so that when it goes out of scope it actually "pulses" the condition variable at this moment. Because otherwise, it would have an optimality issue.

So how come the design of the Monitor object was chosen to be that way ?

Edit:

I found the answer in this paper:
http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64242/implementingcvs.pdf
section "Optimising Signal and Broadcast" and the previous section about NT kernel and how to make Condition Variable on top of Semaphores, which is the reason for introducing the "darned queues".
NOW that makes me a better engineer.

Comment: "if I place the Pulse outside of the lock scope, it doesn't compile. however" : oh, it'll compile - it just won't run; but it is **not** the correct way when using `Monitor`; the pulse must be inside

Comment: Ok, it is not the correct way. but it is the correct way of using condition variables. So need I take it a monitor is just another managed object waaay up in the toposphere of .NET and nowhere near the system ?

Comment: Monitor is implemented inside the CLI, yes; as part of the object-header. So unlike things like `AutoResetEvent`, it doesn't involve going outside the VM to the OS.

Comment: I find that this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958294/why-does-monitor-pulse-need-locked-mutex-net?rq=1 is totally similar and has a very interesting answer from Hans Passant. But it also leads to more questionning about what is that darned ready queue ?

Comment: queues: You probably already were there, but please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization) and look at the images while reading the description. You'l see that there are several queues, and that almost any call on the Monitor is in fact, blocking. Please remember that the point is to have at most one thread "inside the monitor". more shall never be let in. "inside" means the "big inner room" on those pictures. on those pictures, crossing every "door" means to acquire the lock.

Comment: Yes indeed i was there, I liked the idea of presentation using rooms. But the concept you are talking about is just the simple lock concept. (or critical section). condition variables are used for fast notifications, and avoid spin-locks, or timed-sleeping patterns. It just so happens that C# has no vocabulary for this, since apparently Monitor terminology is tangled with critical sections. That seems to confuse you :)

Comment: Ok thanks, and that helped me see some light. But frankly; maybe I HAVE to dive in lengthy msdn (or books even) reads after all; if I really want to get that in depth. For now, I don't have the time, my use case is working, it is enough. But that just doesn't make me a better engineer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And indeed it is idiotic to signal the sleeping thread when you still are in your critical section. Because the sleeping thread CAN'T wake up

`Pulse` *doesn't expect* to get a thread running; it only expects to move a thread between the 2 queues (waiting and ready). The "not go do something" is part of releasing the lock via `Exit` (or the end of a `lock`). In reality, it isn't an issue because `Monitor.Pulse` typically happens right before a `Wait` or an `Exit`.

> Therefore, I hope that .NET or C# Pulse call is actually just flagging the lock object, so that when it goes out of scope it actually "pulses" the condition variable at this moment. Because otherwise, it would have an optimality issue.

Again; these are different issues: moving between waiting and ready is one thing; exiting a lock *already* has all the code to actually activate the next ready thread.

Comment: Should I take it that .NET uses user-space threads ? (i.e. they over-manage threads on the VM to abstract the system ?) How efficient is that ? (it is not rhetoric, I probably just need a link :) )

Comment: @v.oddou that depends on the host; it *can* do, hence the distinction of ManagedThreadId; IIRC SQL Server does that aggressively via the fibre model.

Comment: I remembered what I read in: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads about the Java section. And got scared. Because of that paragraph, I would have thought that C# being modern, would have left out from the spec the constraints that you mention, to let VMs implementors free to map them to kernel threads. But since the article also mention good perf on linux experiments, I suppose Java experience is just an example of how bad Sun people were, and should not scare me into thinking "damn, .NET is repeating history, in a bad way...".

Comment: @v.oddou it isn't a c# concern; it is a runtime/CLI/host issue; but yes, a sophisticated host can do thread mapping itself

Comment: I think it is. Because the language (C#) is specifying something very clearly, then the framework implementors are not free anymore. If C# says Monitors must work with queues, they have to actually implement queues. Who implements thread queues in C++ when they need a wake up event ? of course nobody. Maybe the OS is keeping those queues in the kernel. But that is the point, C# should let the framework free of using directly the system. That can only happen if the specification is loose. Therefore the stress on the language here. E.g. C does not say that << operator will set to 0 the new bytes

Comment: just to finish: so that << operator can be implemented in terms of the actual single CPU instruction that shifts bits. if this CPU is rotating bits, its still OK because the language never said that it could not. If it says something, the instruction has to be emulated to make a shift-with-0-feeding-bits. It is the same thing here, C# over-precise specs seems to force frameworks to use user-space threads, or at least, (useless) managing components on the side (like the queues).

Comment: @v.oddou C# is a *language*, and does not define or control the behavior `Monitor`, which is part of the BCL. The language does have some special treatment of `Monitor`, but only as far as `Enter` / `TryEnter` / `Exit`, for the `lock` keyword

Comment: @v.oddou likewise, the *semantic* of `Monitor` is still very lose; it doesn't even guarantee FIFO, for example; I'm not sure why the need to block for entry to a constrained region has anything to do with dictating the threading model; `Monitor` in a custom BCL could do anything it wanted there to use those threads, or even just a single green thread, and get other work happening instead/

Comment: @v.oddou to make it explicit: " If C# says Monitors must work with queues, they have to actually implement queues." - right; C# ***does not say that***. You are looking at a specific implementation of a library utility, which isn't even defined in the C# specification (other than for `lock`), and then saying "C# boo!"

Comment: @v.oddou re C; if C doesn't define what happens with the right-hand-bits on a `<<`, then I would say C is being a real PITA. You kinda *need to know that*, always. Otherwise, what are going to do: xor it with the last few bits of itself? that sounds tedious and error prone, and sounds exactly like that something that **should** be abstracted away and standardised. Are you sure you don't mean `>>` ? Now *that* I could understand being more open-to-interpretation

Comment: Alright, actually I'm not sure, it was just a vague reminiscence of some anecdote I heard. There is some truth : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087816/confused-by-undefined-c-shift-operator-behavior-and-wrapping-pattern-space but we are seriously drifing :) thanks for all the help ! that's very appreciated.

Comment: "C# does not say that. You are looking at a specific implementation of a library utility" Oh, that, right here, was interesting ! So you're saying that everybody talking about "the ready queue" is making an assumption of the framework actually in use ? So that ready queue's existence is proven how ? since it is not specified, it must be implementation specific, how come do people know so much about runtimes internal details ?

Comment: @v.oddou the *behaviour* is described in the [BCL documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse.aspx), but this has nothing whatsoever to do with the C# specification. Equally, the description of the behavior doesn't specify anything about how it is imlpemented.

Comment: ok yes, thanks, I understand the various vocabulary better now. I'm not near a debugger now, but could you actually watch those queues if you were to watch the variable on which the lock is aqcuired ?

Comment: Ok ok. Finally, do you think they may have no physical presence, and just be a mental construct of the documentation to describe behavior ?

Comment: @v.oddou the implementation is a detail; either way it us unmanaged code. You could download the open-source CLI implementations (the MS early one, Mono, etc) to see approaches

Comment: I think the Monitor.Pulse moves the thread from the waiting queue(since .net does not include a condition variable in the Monitor interface, there can't be more than one waiting queue in their implementation) to the lock queue; the Monitor.Exit() moves the thread from the lock queue to the ready queue.

Comment: @h9uest what do you perceive as the difference between the "lock queue" and the "ready queue"? I think you're imagining one more queue than actually exists. The MSDN documentation explicitly says it moves to the ready queue upon pulse.

Comment: @MarcGravell 1, the difference is, the lock queue is still a waiting queue, while the ready queue is not. The lock queue still represents the blocked state of a thread, while the ready queue represents the ready state of a thread. 2, The MSDN doc indeed explicitly says that. And indeed, I did not check that before I made my statement. 3, However, point 2 does NOT imply I was imagining one more queue - the phrase you were looking for is, "proposing a better solution". The reason is as follows:

Comment: If Microsoft implements the pulse function exactly as it states in the doc, there's a chance that there can be excessive context switching. When pulse is called, the lock is still held. Now the ready queue can pop the front() thread and let it execute. If the front() thread is waiting for the same lock, then it will immediately go back to the waiting state, leading to unnecessary context switching. Since .net enforces pulse() in a lock scope, there's no work-around this inefficiency, if they indeed implement the pulse function as is stated on the MSDN doc.

Comment: In a one lock system, it's no longer 'a chance' - it's going to be inevitability.

Comment: @h9uest no, it is much simpler than that: it is moved to the ready queue in pulse, but it is only Monitor.Exit that dequeues the front of the ready queue and activates that thread.

Comment: @MarcGravell Here's the IL assembler output for Exit, why don't you point out in the next comment which instruction dequeues the ready queue? I did not see anything like that in the ctors, but feel free to dig in by yourself.

On the other hand, I'd like to point out a mistake of yours. Dequeuing the ready queue means context switching.And it's the scheduler's job. Exit just marks a state. Here's a fairly good reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/662735/Internals-of-Windows-Thread 
Section: How OS runs threads
By that, it's easy to tell my "complex" scenario is going to happen.

Comment: // modified due to limit
.method public static void  Exit(object obj)
{
  .custom instance void System.Security.SecuritySafeCriticalAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  .custom instance void System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution.ReliabilityContractAttribute::.ctor(valuetype System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution.Consistency,
                                                                                                valuetype System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution.Cer) = ( 01 00 03 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 ) 
  .custom instance void __DynamicallyInvokableAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
}

Comment: @h9uest where are you looking? IIRC both `Exit` and `Pulse` are `extern` methods. You should not expect the IL to be meaningful.

Comment: mscorlib.dll, System.Threading.Monitor. It's not going to give you all the details right in that output, it's intermediate language, what do you expect? The key thing is, Exit is not going to be responsible for context switching. It's just going to mark a state that the lock is released. In a good implementation, it can be done by moving a thread from lock queue to a ready queue - that's what I've been trying to say. But .NET does not seem to distinguish a condition variable queue and a lock one, therefore the excessive context switching will happen. Nothing can be done as an app programmer.

Comment: @h9uest I'm perfectly comfortable reading IL; but that is an `extern` method: there *is nothing to read*. I don't accept your premise or your conclusion, at least not on the information you've provided so far.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, I should have been able to tell from your comments that you've never programmed with pthreads. It's a bit difficult to convince you because you don't have the concept of a condition variable. .Net monitor shields you from that level of complexity. It's fine. If you think the lock queue is all that you need for a waiting queue, keep thinking that.

Answer (score 1):

You did not understood the basic problem of synchronization. What is a 'monitor', what does it mean that a thread sleeps and what does it mean that it is about to be woken up?

A monitor is a mid-level synchronization structure. This is not a low-level petty volatile boolean flag with bus-halting XCHG operation, and this is not high-level thread pool handler that requires dozens of other special mechanisms..

On a monitor, **MANY** threads may sleep. There are **logical queues** out there that i.e. preserver order of being put to sleep/woken up, or mechanisms that guarantee proper time scheduling and fairnees. I will not get into details, all of it is out there on the web, even on wiki.

Add to that that the operation is PULSE. Pulse is instantenous. It does not "stick". Pulse will wake those now sleeping. If after the pulse another one check the monitor, it will go to sleep.

Now imagine: you have a queue of 5 sleeping threads. One thread (6th) wants now to pulse them, and yet another (7th) wants to check the monitor.

6th and 7th are running in parallel, truly simultaneously, since you have quad-core CPU.

So, tell me, what would happen to the queue's implementtion if the 6th starts pulsing andwaking and removing woken threads from the queue, and in the same time the 7th one starts adding itself there?

To solve that, the internal queues would have to be internally synchronized and locked, so only one thread at time modifies them.

Um wait. We just stumbled upon a case where we wanted to SYNCHRONIZE something, and to do it properly we need to SYNCHRONIZE on another thing? Not good.

Therefore, the actual LOCK is done EXTERNALLY before you talk to the monitor itself. This is to achieve SINGLE LOCKING, instead of introduce several layers of hierarchical locks.

That way it is simplier, faster, and more resource-friendly.

Comment: I think I get synchronization good enough, I was using boost mutex and condition_variable a lot in the past with, I think, correct understanding. I also used the Win32 equivalent primitives. And now in C# the same "concept" is turned upside-down. So you must understand my puzzling. And all of your explanation only makes it more tangled. You want to say that Monitors are between XCHG and poor handler, but now you just made it look exaclty like a poor handler. Thanks though :)

Comment: IIRC, when using condition variables, to raise/change them you also had to lock them first. Even if it was done completely out of your sight, it was still performed within the API call. Here it is just on the eyes so that you remember about the fact that the API call may instantly put you to sleep, just because the sync is temporarily blocked.

Comment: Well, that is covered by the two links I put in the question. The first is explaining clearly why notification has to be made after the lock : "prevent useless context switches". Which is also mentioned in the "Linked Question". The MSDN sample also clearly notifies (Wake..) after the lock.

Comment: Hmm.. after thinking about it a little more, I think I know what bothers you - aren't you too focused on (autoreset)events ? For simple cases, they are in fact very similar to Monitors. However, the main difference is that autoresetevent is notification-only. With autoresetevent, you cannot thread-safely do operations like a "notification-and-statusupdate" because after the notifications the threads might already be running and don't see the status update. You could do a "statusupdate-and-then-notification" of course, but that means that YOU have to control and keep the order manually.

Comment: With OO languages where there's a lot of delegation, it often is hard to tell what is the actual order of something.. With Monitor, the order is irrelevant, since **during the notification** you **have the lock**. Until you free it, yo ucan do anything in any order. You are doing a "block of things" in sync with the notification. You begin-the-notification-phase, do things, and then you end-the-notification-phase. That's more powerful than just "ping them" to wake. Of course, the question is: whether you need that in your case? if you do not see the use for it, use the autoRevent to wake them.

Comment: I understand that the source of my bothering can seem like a nitpicking. It is purely coming from my past with POSIX/Win32 implementations of the same concept. Like seen with Marc Gravell, the thing is that C# is acutally pretty far from those system libraries. And that is the reason why it is designed that way. We are abstracted from the concept that I was thinking it was mapping in a direct-to-kernel fashion. Though the thing is that it does not. And that is the answer. It is just a high-level manager of all sync primitives in one big terminology.